# How to make my vue component connect to my node server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, vue.js

Hey guys am building a SPA(Single Page Application) chat app using ***Vuejs for front and Laravel 5.4 for my backend API.***
To achieve realtime communication experience i build a basic node server with express and installed ***vue-socket.io*** on my vue frontend project but the vue project seem not to be connected to node server. Please what i'm i missing here?
This is what i have done:

**server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();

var server = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var redis = require('redis');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

function logData(message) {
    var d = new Date();
    var time = '[' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() + '] '
    console.log(time + message);
}

function logMultipleData(message, channel, data) {
    var d = new Date();
    var time = '[' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() + '] '
    console.log(time + message + channel + data);
}

server.listen(3000, function() {
    logData('Chat server booted on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('new client connected');
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('message');
    redisClient.on('message', function (channel, message) {
        logMultipleData('New Message In Queune', channel, message);
    })
});
```

**Main.js** (this file is in vue frontend project)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Router from './routes.js'

import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'; 

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VueSocketIO, 'http://localhost.com:8890');

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router: Router
})
```

**Test.vue**(my test component)

```
<template>
<!--Mask-->
<div class="view">
  <img class="background" src="/src/assets/images/background.jpg" alt="">
  <!--Intro content-->
  <div class="full-bg-img flex-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4 offset-4">
          <!--Form with header-->
          <div class="card section">

            <div class="progress">
              <div class="indeterminate" style="width: 70%"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="card-block">


              <!--Header-->
              <!-- <div class="form-header  purple darken-4">
                <h3><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Register:</h3>
              </div> -->

              <!--Body-->
              <button @click="clickButton">Ping Server</button>
              <blockquote class="blockquote bq-primary">
                <!-- <p class="bq-title">User Name</p> -->
                please enter a username or take one of the suggestions below.
              </blockquote>

               <form v-on:submit.prevent="handleLoginFormSubmit()">
                <div class="md-form">
                  <!-- <i class="fa fa-envelope-o prefix"></i> -->
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Email / Username" id="email" v-model="login.email" class="form-control validate" required autofocus>
                  <div class="error-log"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center">
                  <button id="load-btn" class="btn btn-deep-purple" disabled><set-loader></set-loader></button>
                  <button id="login-btn" class="btn btn-deep-purple">Login</button>
                </div>
              </form>


            </div>

            <!--Footer-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <!-- Stepers Wrapper -->
              <ul class="stepper stepper-horizontal">

                <!-- First Step -->
                <li class="active">
                  <a href="#!">
                                                    <span class="circle">1</span>
                                            </a>
                </li>

                <!-- Second Step -->
                <li class="">
                  <a href="#!">
                                                    <span class="circle">2</span>
                                            </a>
                </li>

                <!-- Third Step -->
                <li class="">
                  <a href="#!" disabled>
                                                    <span class="circle">3</span>
                                            </a>
                </li>

                <!-- Fourth Step -->
                <li class="">
                  <a href="#!" disabled>
                                                    <span class="circle">4</span>
                                            </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--/Form with header-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/Intro content-->
</div>
<!--/.Mask-->
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io';
import Chip from './helper/chipNoavatar.vue'
import Loader from './helper/loaders/multicolors/small.vue'
Vue.use(VueSocketIO, 'http://localhost.com:3000');
export default {
  components: {
    'set-chip': Chip,
    'set-loader': Loader
  },
  data() {
    return {
      login: {
        email: '',
      }
    }
  },
  created() {

  },
  sockets:{
    connect: function(){
      console.log('socket connected')
    },
    disconnect: function(){
      console.log('socket disconnected')
    },
    customEmit: function(val){
      console.log('this method was fired by the socket server. eg: io.emit("customEmit", data)')
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    //do something after mounting vue instance
    // Data Picker Initialization
    // $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    //   min: new Date(1910, 0, 0),
    //   max: new Date(2012, 0, 0)
    // });
  },
  methods: {
    handleLoginFormSubmit() {
        // $("#login-btn").hide()
        // $("#load-btn").show()

        var postData = {
          client_id: 2,
          client_secret: this.$afrobukConfig.client_secret,
          grant_type: 'password',
          username: this.login.email,
          remember: true
        }

        this.$http.post("api/test", postData)
          .then(response => {

            console.log(response.body)
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    },

    clickButton: function(val){
        // $socket is socket.io-client instance
        this.$socket.emit('emit_method', val);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**Please can anyone help me with this? Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things. First I am going to assume that you are using the vue-cli webpack starter since you have a main.js and a .vue file.

You only need to use the socket.io middleware on the front end in your main.js. This will add a $socket property to all components that allows you to interact with the socket. You should remove the `Vue.use(SocketIO)` from `Test.vue`

Second, in main.js you have the connection set up as

```
Vue.use(VueSocketIO, 'http://localhost.com:8890');
```

when it should be

```
Vue.use(VueSocketIO, 'http://localhost:3000');
```

localhost.com is not your socket server. if your socket server is in dns or your host file it would be something like `myserver.domain.com` but since you are running the socket server and vue frontend on the same machine you can just use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` (in most cases) as the server address

If you want to use port 8890, then you will need to change

```
server.listen(3000, function() {
```

to

```
server.listen(8890, function() {
```

in your server code.